# Visualizing nice circuits in Qiskit

Tags: programming, qiskit

This is what drawing a circuit looks like in the Qiskit textbook:

[image]

and this is the ugly version I am stuck with in my own notebooks:

[image]

On their [Prerequisites](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-prerequisites/setting-the-environment.html) page they write:

[image]

However, there is no .qiskit file in my home directory, and I can't locate it anywhere else. I installed it simply with the usual pip install command, without setting up any virtual environment, so that may be the issue. I am not a Linux expert so perhaps there is something simple I am missing.

How can I set up this configuration file? Creating a .qiskit directory manually doesn't do the job.

Comment: Rather than changing the default, you can request the mpl backend each time using `.draw(output='mpl')'.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Would still be nice to figure out where that damn file is stored though.

Comment: Hey! I wrote that "ugly" circuit drawer. I feel a bit disparaged ;)

Comment: Oops, sorry :) I should have rather called it _charmingly rustic_ or _tastefully minimalistic_ perhaps...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As James noted in the comment. You can use the `.draw( output = 'mpl', ... )`  or  to help you to get a nicer figure. That is, suppose I have the following circuit:

```
q_0: ┤ X ├┤M├─────────
     ├───┤└╥┘┌─┐      
q_1: ┤ X ├─╫─┤M├──────
     ├───┤ ║ └╥┘┌─┐   
q_2: ┤ H ├─╫──╫─┤M├───
     ├───┤ ║  ║ └╥┘┌─┐
q_3: ┤ H ├─╫──╫──╫─┤M├
     └───┘ ║  ║  ║ └╥┘
c: 4/══════╩══╩══╩══╩═
           0  1  2  3
```

which can be created by running the code:

```
from qiskit import QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister, QuantumCircuit
from numpy import pi

qreg_q = QuantumRegister(4, 'q')
creg_c = ClassicalRegister(4, 'c')
circuit = QuantumCircuit(qreg_q, creg_c)

circuit.x(qreg_q[0])
circuit.x(qreg_q[1])
circuit.h(qreg_q[2])
circuit.h(qreg_q[3])
circuit.measure(qreg_q[0], creg_c[0])
circuit.measure(qreg_q[1], creg_c[1])
circuit.measure(qreg_q[2], creg_c[2])
circuit.measure(qreg_q[3], creg_c[3])
```

then by specifying:

```
circuit.draw( output = 'mpl', style={'name': 'bw'}, plot_barriers= True, initial_state = True, scale = 1)
```

I will get the figure:

[image]

and if i specify:

```
circuit.draw( output = 'latex',style={'name': 'bw'}, plot_barriers= True, initial_state = True, scale = 1)
```

I will get the figure:

[image]

and if you want to **save the image file**, then include the file name in the option. That is, something like:

```
circuit.draw( 'mpl',style={'name': 'bw'},filename= 'MyCircuit', plot_barriers= True, initial_state = True, scale = 1)
```